Can I use an IF Statement as the Value if True within an IF Statement? (=if(H9="Y", if(E9="1", E9*G9, E9*G9-F8), 0)) in Sheets/Excel?
Trying to resolve an equation where I need the value IF TRUE to be dependent on another IF Statement. The Equation calculates and doesn't throw an error but the expected value is incorrect. Is this type of equation possible?
My equation:
=if(H9="Y", if(E9="1", E9G9, E9G9-F8), 0)
If a Cell is "Y", AND another cell is "1" I need a certain value (Cell X Cell), else all other values of the nested IF are (Cell X Cell - Cell).
Example Data showing wrong value returned:
Columns E-I - where H9 = Y, E9 = 1, G9 = 3.75, and F8 = 21, I9 contains statement = -17.25, E9G9 = 3.75, E9G9-F8 = -17.25.
6   21  3.75    n   0
1   1   3.75    y   -17.25
If the statement worked as I intended, I9 would be 3.75, but it is taking the Value if False instead of True.
Can anyone help me find the error in my approach, or does this equation not work for my intention?
Thanks!

Is this an Excel formula or something else?

Hi Jay, It's using Google Sheets, and yes it's an attempt at a formula which I am not sure if it has the same capabilities as Excel. I always thought they were identical but it's not my area of expertise. Also, I am new to creating formulas in spreadsheets with if statements, and other logic, so I am not sure if I am taking the right approach. Thanks!
